# Como transformar pin code em variavel PHP?

Tags: javascript, html

É um teclado automatico que assim que eu digitar os 6 digitos ele executa o form levando os numeros digitados em uma variavel php para outra pagina, porém quando eu clico no primeiro numero ele já executa o form..

```
<form id="Form" action="action.php" method="post">

      <div id="fields">
        <div class="grid">
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
          <div contenteditable="true" name="textBox" class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-6 numberfield"><span></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="numbers">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>1</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>2</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>3</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>4</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>5</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>6</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>7</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>8</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>9</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"><button>0</button></div>
          <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var enterCode = "";
    enterCode.toString();

    $("#numbers button").click(function() {

      var clickedNumber = $(this).text().toString();
      enterCode = enterCode + clickedNumber;
      var lengthCode = parseInt(enterCode.length);
      lengthCode--;
      $("#fields .numberfield:eq(" + lengthCode + ")").addClass("active");

    });
  });
});


$(function() {
  $('#textBox').bind('change keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
      $('#Form').submit();
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: ja sua function de click, passa para ela o evento: `$("#numbers button").click(function(event) {` e e dentro do método cancele o evento para evitar o submit com o comando `event.preventDefault();`. Veja se resolve, quiser posso postar uma resposta explicando

Comment: Por favor, sou iniciante se você pudesse fazer um exemplo seria muito bom @RicardoPontual

Comment: posso fazer, mas enquanto isso teste essas alterações que comentei

Comment: beleza, vou testar, porém queria pegar o valor também e mandar ele como variavel php no form para action.php

Comment: Eu testei e ainda continua, quando clico ele faz o submit

Comment: olhe esse exemplo com o seu código, não faz submit ao clicar nos botões https://jsfiddle.net/c2tp4hms/

Comment: Porem ali no div grid, eu digito 6 numeros até ele executar o submit, isso que eu queria, e pegar esses numeros digitados em uma variavel pra proxima pagina

Answer (score 1):

o padrão da tag button, é ser type=submit, mude para type button:

```
<button type="button">1</button>
```

assim o formulário não será enviado ao clicar no botão.